# AutoMapper and gRPC - ConvertUsing() with nullable strings

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, grpc

I am using AutoMapper to convert DTOs to entities and back. The DTOs are generated per protobuf compiler. The problem is, that those DTOs don't allow for null value strings.

To bypass that issue i came up with the following code (simplified Example):

```
public class Entity
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<string?, string>()    // nullable string to string
                .ConvertUsing(src => src ?? string.Empty);

            cfg.CreateMap<string, string?>()    // string to nullable string
                .ConvertUsing(src => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src) ? null : src);

            cfg.CreateMap<Entity, Dto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Entity>();

        }).CreateMapper();

        Dto dto = mapper.Map<Dto>(new Entity());
        Entity entity = mapper.Map<Entity>(dto);

        Console.WriteLine(dto.Title is null);   // Result true
        Console.WriteLine(entity.Title is null);  // Result true
    }
}
```

The problem here is that AutoMapper doesn't interprete the *string?* as seperate type. So it converts using *CreateMap<string?, string>()* and then also converts using *CreateMap<string?, string>()*. That means that if i would change those configuration orders both *Console.WriteLines()* would print *False*.

As a workaround i am now using the following code on all my Entity->Dto mappings instead of the <string?, string> mapping.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Entity, Dto>()
                .AddTransform<string?>(value => value ?? string.Empty);
```

Is there any global solution to this problem. How do other people handle the quirks of gRPC-Classes with AutoMapper?

Comment: You only need `CreateMap<string, string>`(or a transformer). That would cover _all_ cases.

Comment: This might work. But i'm afraid of some unpredictable behaviours when i simply replace all empty strings to null strings or reverse. Or do you have a more complex mapping in mind? If so I would be glad about an example.

Comment: It doesn't have to be _all_ strings. A transformer can be set per map or per profile.